# Retrieving values from arbitrary input fields

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm creating an addon that adds new rows of input fields to be filled up by the user, the problem I have is I can't find a way for the operator to print all the values of all the slots.

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Operator
from bpy.types import Scene
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty

class SceneItems(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_string_old_material : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "", default ="")
    my_string_new_material : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "", default ="")
    
class AddButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.add_button_operator"
    bl_label = "Add New Slot"

    def execute(self, context):
        id = len(context.scene.newbutton)
        new = context.scene.newbutton.add()
        return {'FINISHED'}        

class RemoveButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.remove_button_operator"
    bl_label = "Remove Button"

    id : bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.scene.newbutton.remove(self.id)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class PrintButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.print_items"
    bl_label = "Print Slots Values"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("I want to print all the strings from my_string_old_material and my_string_new_material")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SlotsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Slots"
    bl_category = "My Slots"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        self.layout.operator("custom.print_items", icon="LINENUMBERS_ON") #LINENUMBERS_OFF, ANIM
        row=layout.row()
        scale_row = row.row()
        self.layout.operator("scene.add_button_operator")
        
        for idx, item in enumerate(context.scene.newbutton):
            row = self.layout.row(align=True)

            row.prop(item, "my_string_old_material")
            row.separator(factor = 1)
            row.prop(item, "my_string_new_material")
            row.separator(factor = 1)
            row.scale_x = 1
            row.operator("scene.remove_button_operator", text='', icon = "PANEL_CLOSE").id = idx        
        
classes = (
    SceneItems,
    AddButtonOperator,
    SlotsPanel,
    RemoveButtonOperator,
    PrintButtonOperator,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.newbutton = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type = SceneItems)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: `for item in context.scene.newbutton: print(item.my_string_old_material, item.my_string_new_material)`?

Comment: That did the trick ,thank you. I will accept your answer.